# Closing a connection in stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

Unfortunately working with .Net forms, I opened a database connection and after executing a query, I forget to close the connection. Now my routine is calling again and again to that query and in a result connection pool is quickly filling up.

Is there any option to close the connection pool manually through stored procedure?

Comment: use a Using block, which will automatically close and dispose of your connection. do not try to close the connection from the server side.

Comment: OR if it is a one time fix, run sp_who2 and find all processes that are opened as a result of your process and use the KILL keyword to close. CAUTION. use sparingly and as last resort.

Comment: @jeremy is correct. You should also be able to see the specific query last executed from the thread, and how long it has been idle, to ensure it's the one you intended to kill.

Comment: I cant set a hot fix in Executable. The only option is to any possible Stored Procedure fix.

Comment: unfortunately there is no good way. Either fix the problem in the exe and redeploy, or advise your client to reboot the sql server every day until you fix it.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't close a connection after you lose the reference to it, but you can [kill the session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) on sql server, causing all transactions to rollback and procedures to stop running